Find hierarchical shareholders relationships: refactor nested if in Python
I want to find shareholder relationships between companies.
In the below example, 'Person 1' has directly 50% of 'Company 1' shares, and then we need to check if 'Company 1' also have shares of other companies.
'Company 1' has 50% of 'Company 2' share and 20% of 'Company 3'. It means 'Person 1' indirectly has some share in 'Company 2' and 'Company 3'.
The desired output in this example is:
Company 1 : Person 1 , 0.5
Company 2 : Company 1 , 0.5
Company 3 : Company 2 , 0.2
This is my code:
companies = {
    'Company 1': {
        'Person 1': 0.5,
        'Person 2': 0.3,
        'Person 3': 0.2,
    },
    'Company 2': {
        'Person 4': 0.25,
        'Company 1': 0.5,
        'Person 5': 0.25,
    },
    'Company 3': {
        'Person 5': 0.6,
        'Person 6': 0.2,
        'Company 2': 0.2,
    },
}

def is_shareholder_in_company(company, companies, shareholder_name):
    company_shareholders = companies[company]

    for shareholder, ownership_percentage in company_shareholders.items():
        if shareholder_name == shareholder:
            print(company, ':',shareholder, ',', ownership_percentage)
            return True

for i in companies:
    if is_shareholder_in_company(i, companies, 'Person 1'):
        temp_name = i
        for j in companies:
            if is_shareholder_in_company(j, companies, i):
                temp_name = j
                for x in companies:
                    if is_shareholder_in_company(x, companies, j):
                        temp_name = x


How do I refactor nested if's and loops that were hardcoded in the last part? The count of nests is dependent on 'companies' data, and it is unknown. In this example, there are three layers of nests.

You can use recursion to see the shae distribution in the companies.
def find_ownership_chain(companies, shareholder_name, current_chain=None):
    if current_chain is None:
        current_chain = []

    for company, shareholders in companies.items():
        if shareholder_name in shareholders:
            current_chain.append((company, shareholder_name, shareholders[shareholder_name]))
            # If the shareholder is another company, recurse here
            if shareholder_name in companies:
                return find_ownership_chain(companies, company, current_chain)
            return current_chain
    return current_chain

def trace_ownership(companies, starting_shareholder):
    chain = find_ownership_chain(companies, starting_shareholder)
    for company, shareholder, percentage in chain:
        print(f"{company}: {shareholder}, {percentage}")

# for your example abve
trace_ownership(companies, 'Person 1')


thanks but it dosen't give the desired output.

Be careful of recursion, because of what will happen if company 1 owns shares in company 2, and company 1 owns shares in company 2.

To perform lookups of company ownership, it is more efficient to restructure your input as a shareholder name-index dict of set of owner companies:
ownership = {}
for company, owners in companies.items():
    for owner in owners:
        ownership.setdefault(owner, set()).add(company)

so ownership would become:
{'Company 1': {'Company 2'},
 'Company 2': {'Company 3'},
 'Person 1': {'Company 1'},
 'Person 2': {'Company 1'},
 'Person 3': {'Company 1'},
 'Person 4': {'Company 2'},
 'Person 5': {'Company 3', 'Company 2'},
 'Person 6': {'Company 3'}}

With the said data structure a name can be efficiently identified as an owner a of a company by checking if either the company is in the set of companies owned by the name, or if recursively, any of the companies owned by the name is an owner of the given company.
To avoid infinite recursion in cases where companies are mutually owned, we can use a set to keep track of names already visited in the current stack:
def is_shareholder_in_company(company, shareholder_name):
    def is_shareholder(name):
        if name in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(name)
        owneds = ownership.get(name, {})
        return company in owneds or any(map(is_shareholder, owneds))
    seen = set()
    return is_shareholder(shareholder_name)

so that:
print(is_shareholder_in_company('Company 3', 'Person 1'))

outputs:
True

Demo here

You can think of your problem in terms of a DiGraph, then ask for the dfs_edges :
import networkx as nx

DG = nx.DiGraph(
    [
        (sh, co, {"perct": perct})
        for co, det in companies.items()
        for sh, perct in det.items()
    ]
)

def ownership_of(n):
    print(
        "\n".join(
            f'{v}: {u}, {DG.edges[u,v]["perct"]}'
            for (u, v) in nx.dfs_edges(DG, n)
        )
    )

Output :
>>> ownership_of("Person 1")

# Company 1: Person 1, 0.5
# Company 2: Company 1, 0.5
# Company 3: Company 2, 0.2



the chart is great, how do you draw this chart?

With matplotlib or pygraphviz. For the latter, in a notebook (any kind), do : from IPython.display; Image(nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(DG).draw(format="png", prog="dot")).
